# Conditional complex column type

Tags: tables, conditionals, columns

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

    % \newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\hspace{0pt}\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
    % \newcolumntype{B}[1]{>{\hspace{0pt}\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\hspace{0pt}\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % linksbündig mit Breitenangabe
    \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\hspace{0pt}\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % zentriert mit Breitenangabe
    \newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\hspace{0pt}\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % rechtsbündig mit Breitenangabe

    % non working columntype pseudocode 
    \newcolumntype{Z}[5]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{left}{!{\vrule width #4}>{\columncolor{#3}\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}{\vrule width #5}}%
    {\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{center}{!{\vrule width #4}>{\columncolor{#3}\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}{\vrule width #5}}%
    {!{\vrule width #4}>{\columncolor{#3}\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}{\vrule width #5}}%
    }%



\begin{document}

% desired results
\begin{tabular}{|L{2cm}|C{2cm}|R{2cm}}
first row & A & CC\\
second row& B& CA
\end{tabular}

% pseudocode
\begin{tabular}{|Z{2cm}{left}{white}{0}{0}|Z{2cm}{center}{white}{0}{0}|Z{2cm}{right}{white}{0}{0}|}
first row & A & CC\\
second row& B& CA
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Is there any way to create conditional complex column types (or column types with more arguments)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Z`-column definition is malformed or incomplete. Since it seems like you only want to condition on whether the user supplies `left`, `center` or `right`, here's how you can achieve that:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,colortbl}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\newcolumntype{Z}[5]{%
  !{\vrule width #4}
  >{\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#2}{left}=0 \raggedright\arraybackslash\fi
    \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#2}{center}=0 \centering\arraybackslash\fi
    \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#2}{right}=0 \raggedleft\arraybackslash\fi
    \columncolor{#3}}
  p{#1}
  !{\vrule width #5}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|L{2cm}|C{2cm}|R{2cm}}
  first row  & A & CC \\
  second row & B & CA
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{|Z{2cm}{left}{red}{2pt}{2pt}|Z{2cm}{center}{blue}{1pt}{1pt}|Z{2cm}{right}{green}{0pt}{0pt}|}
  first row  & A & CC \\
  second row & B & CA
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```